# How to create a custom @using code block in razor

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a custom partial view that uses the same syntax as the `@using(Html.BeginForm())`

I already have the view working with an extension to the HtmlHelper, but it currently takes a string: `@Html.InfoBox("title", "<div>Content of the box</div>")`

Which calls this partial view:

```
<div class="info-card">
    <span class="info-title">@Model.Title</span>
    <div>
        @Html.Raw(Model.Description)
    </div>
</div>
```

So I'd like something like this:

```
@using(Html.InfoBox("title"))
{
    <div>Content of the box</div>
}
```

Comment: `@` is just a handy way to introduce a C# statement or expression inside a razor view. `@using` is just a `using` statement. To make an expression compatible with `using` it needs to implement `System.IDisposable`.

Comment: Yes but how do I wrap it in the html, I added the view to the post